# Collapse and expand object details in python django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

In Django admin interface, it is better to use collapse and expand object details for showing the objects. The following model is used to collapse and expand object details.

```
email=EmailField()
password=PassWordField()
created_time=DateTimeField()
```

when user request a new password, we will send it to them, which is stored in the database. In admin interface, by default it will be in collapse mode, if user click the email it will expand.

Default example as follows:

```
+ email:xxx@xx.com,id:1, name: robert 
+ email:xxx@xy.com,id:2, name: rock
```

Expand example as follows:

```
-email:xxx@xx.com,id:1, name: robert  
   password:xcxcxc,created_time:29-09-2015,
   password:affsdf,created_time:15-09-2015,
   password:sgkgskg,created_time:28-07-2015,
```

Kindly guide me to achieve the above task.

Comment: Have you read the FineManual ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets

Comment: I am trying collapse and expand method it shows only inside the object. I need to display collapse and expand method on click on object list.

Comment: Then you'll have to implement it by yourself.